# User Defined Function returning same results on different tabs

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have this code that analyzes stock returns, I'm planning on having 10-20 tabs with a different stock on each tab:

```
Function myStrategyReturn(sell As Double, buy As Double) As Double

Dim x As Double

Application.Volatile

changes = Range("H2:H263")

PreviousFlag = "Buy"

startingBalance = Range("P5").Value

newBal = Range("P5").Value

For i = UBound(changes) To 1 Step -1

x = changes(i, 1)
If PreviousFlag = "Sell" Then

    If x <= buy Then

        PreviousFlag = "Buy"

    Else

        newBal = newBal

    End If

ElseIf x <= buy Or i = UBound(changes) Then

    newBal = (newBal * (1 + x))
    PreviousFlag = "Buy"

ElseIf x < sell And x > buy Then 'our return is below the sell threshold, but above the buy

    newBal = (newBal * (1 + x))
    PreviousFlag = "Buy"

ElseIf x >= sell Then

    newBal = (newBal * (1 + x))
    PreviousFlag = "Sell"

End If

Next i

myStrategyReturn = ((newBal - startingBalance) / startingBalance)

End Function
```

The problem I'm having is each tab is currently returning the same result. The formula inputs are always the same, but range H2:H263 is different. For some reason the formula keeps returning the returns of the tab where I last did a full calculation.

Comment: It is obvious that the code will return the same result for ever... If you want something different you must introduce into the function the worksheet object. Otherwise, it will all the time will return the active sheet analysis result.

Comment: Change `Function myStrategyReturn(sell As Double, buy As Double) As Double` to `Function myStrategyReturn(sell As Double, buy As Double, rng as range) As Double` and then pass the range in that function

Comment: I am referring to `Range("H2:H263")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gary's solution would work, here's an alternative that captures your inputs in the formula which is better than trying to have it coded in VBA.

```
Function myStrategyReturn(sell As Double, buy As Double, Changes As Range, startingBalance As Range) As Double

Dim x As Double, i As Long, previousFlag As String


'may not need this.
Application.Volatile

previousFlag = "Buy"

Dim Newbal As Double

Newbal = startingBalance.Value

For i = UBound(Changes) To 1 Step -1

x = Changes(i, 1)
If previousFlag = "Sell" Then

    If x <= buy Then

        previousFlag = "Buy"

    Else

        Newbal = Newbal

    End If

ElseIf x <= buy Or i = UBound(Changes) Then

    Newbal = (Newbal * (1 + x))

    previousFlag = "Buy"

ElseIf x < sell And x > buy Then 'our return is below the sell threshold, but above the buy

    Newbal = (Newbal * (1 + x))

    previousFlag = "Buy"

ElseIf x >= sell Then

    Newbal = (Newbal * (1 + x))

    previousFlag = "Sell"

End If

Next i

myStrategyReturn = ((Newbal - startingBalance.Value2) / startingBalance.Value2)

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

A code line like:

```
changes = Range("H2:H263")
```

will pick data from the ***ActiveSheet*** rather than  sheet on which a UDF appears in a cell.